# suspicious crawler activity

Tags: security, googlebot

I'm noticing that I get accesses

```
66.249.66.198 - - [01/Jul/2011:17:13:46 +0200] "GET /img/clip.incubus.torrent.phtml HTTP/1.1" 404 143 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
66.249.66.198 - - [01/Jul/2011:17:13:48 +0200] "GET /img/clip.global.deejays.download.phtml HTTP/1.1" 404 143 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

that files don't exist and there is no file on my site that has this content (I hope).

Why is googlebot trying out these links?

reverse dns and whois state that 66.249.66.198 is really googlebot.

Comment: Two guesses: 1) It's linked from elsewhere 2) Those files are common on sites infected with some malware and google tries to check for that malware so it can warn users.

Comment: I was just suspicious because we are talking about >280000 accesses and it's still going

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If domain name is new (you recently bought it) then Google may still try to get old URLs (not because it remembers those links (it will de-index such not-working-for-a-long-time links) but because there is still a site that has links to this domain)
2. Wherever those links were published there maybe a typo in URL (domain name) and they are pointing to your domain (e.g. `hellokitten.com` instead of `hellkitten.com`).
3. I very doubt that it is Google checking for malware using SO many different URLs which look very similarly.
4. The URLs you showed so far suggest they are probably related to a torrent site. As we know Google does not like torrent sites any more. Maybe it had some suspicion (don't know what it may be) and checks your site for some common URLs that it founds on other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably because someone linked there once.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about how those spiders work, but google is very sophisticated. It could be any number of reasons. My guess is googlebot is trying to establish some relationship between your site and one with those files. Maybe it suspects they are related, and is testing that out.

Comment: Who on earth is linking tons (I see thousands of accesses) of links (like /img/clon.hunter.crack.phtml, /img/clone.dvd.3.6.1.0..serial.number.user.name.crack.phtml) on random sites like mine? perhaps some people exploiting googlebot to crawl the world for them?